# Why wont my widget work inside of wirecloud?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have made the following widget using nothing but html, css and js. This works just fine by itself when you search for keywords that ixist in our DB (such as peach or strawberry):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Search Seller widget</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>

  #mapCanvas {
    width: 550px;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid; color: #59C0DF;

  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  #tbl{
     border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  #tbl, td, th{
    border: 2px solid #70B8FF;
     padding: 5px;

  }
  th{
    font-style: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #59C0DF;
  }

  .btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.textbox {
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline:0;
    height:25px;
    width: 120px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize(45.2671, 19.8335,0)"> <!--bgcolor="#E6E6FA"-->

<div id="top">

  <label>
    <input type="url" id="url" class="textbox" value="">
  </label>

  <label>
    <button id="get" class="btn">GET</button>
  </label>
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" id="City" class="textbox" value="" readonly>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text" id="Company" class="textbox" value="" readonly>
    <label>Latitude</label>
    <input type="text" id="Lat" class="textbox" value="" readonly>
    <label>Longitude</label>
    <input type="text" id="Lon" class="textbox" value="" readonly>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</br>
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:380px; border-style: solid; border-color: #3498db; display: none;"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="http://www.panonit.com" target="_blank"> <img src="PanonitLogo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:160px;height:75px; margin-top:15px" > </a>
    <a href="http://www.finish-project.eu/" target="_blank"> <img src="Cropped.png" alt="Logo" style="width:160px;height:75px;margin-left:15px; margin-top:15px" > </a>
    <a href="http://ec.europa.eu/index_en.htm" target="_blank"> <img src="European.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:160px;height:75px;margin-left:15px; margin-top:15px" > </a>
</div>


<script>
var obj;

var cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
function doCORSRequest(options, printResult) {
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open(options.method, cors_api_url + options.url);
x.onload = x.onerror = function() {
  printResult(
    options.method + ' ' + options.url + '\n' +
    x.status + ' ' + x.statusText + '\n\n' +
    (x.responseText || '')
  );
};
x.send(options.data);
}
// Bind event
(function() {
var urlField = document.getElementById('url');
var obj;


document.getElementById('get').onclick = function(e) {
    var glat;
    var glon;
  e.preventDefault();
  doCORSRequest({
    method: this.id = 'GET',
    url: 'trace.panonit.com/widgets/GetFieldCoordinates/' + urlField.value
  }, function printResult(result) {
    result = result.substring(result.length, result.indexOf('{'));
    obj = JSON.parse(result);

    var cityField = document.getElementById('City');
    cityField.value = obj.City;
    var company = document.getElementById('Company');
    company.value = obj.Company;
    var lat = document.getElementById('Lat');
    lat.value = obj.Lat;
    glat = lat.value;
    var lon = document.getElementById('Lon');
    lon.value = obj.Lon;
    glon = lon.value;
    if(obj.Lat==null || obj.Lon ==null)
    {
       //initialize(glat, glon);
       document.getElementById('City').value = "City not found";
       document.getElementById('Company').value = "Company not found";
       document.getElementById('Lat').value = "Latitude not found";
       document.getElementById('Lon').value = "Longitude not found";
       initialize(45.2671, 19.8335,0);
    }
    else {
        initialize(glat, glon,1);
    }

  });
};
})();


function initialize(lat, lon, displayMarker) {
  document.getElementById('map').style.display = "";
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);
  if(displayMarker==1){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat,lon),
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Crop marker!'
                    });
  }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I convert it to a widget with the help of fispace's add on in eclipse and then proceed to upload it in fiware lab's or fispace's wirecloud thats when it shows an error missing api key. So I got google's api key and appended it like so:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBGrI_BKBCPZfOCskNEH5B5wiJhuV1yKeI"></script>
```

**Yet still I end up with a grayed out map inside of wire-cloud.** 
Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Any messages in the javascript console?

Comment: Yes, error 403 and an error that no google api key was found. If you have a fiware lab account you can see the widget for yourself. Its called seller location

Comment: Or try create the the simple example from the google maps tutorial as widget. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @Vrankela, are you modifying your widget? I have been taking a look into "Panonit/SellerLocation/0.0.20" and the html provided in stack overflow differs from the one used in the widget. Anyway, it's not required to provide an API key for using the Google Maps API, take a look into the standard [map-viewer widget](https://github.com/Wirecloud/map-viewer-widget) for an example.

Comment: Yes @ÁlvaroArranz i am trying different solutions to fix my problem but I dont understand why the conversion from the working html (the latest one) doesn't fix the issue. Have you tried running the html I provided and confirmed that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get errors due mixed content when using the original HTML file. Using "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" and "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" for loading jquery and google maps (take into account the `s` of https) fixes the problem. At least when I search `peach` the widget shows a `Arsen Agro` company.

Comment: The original html file works just fine, I know that. Its when I convert it to a widget and upload it to wirecloud that it stops working.

I've tried both scenarios where I put or even leave out the s in htpps and I still cant manage to convert the html file to a functional .wgt.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. I was using google.com instead of googleapis.com (I hadn't noticed the difference in your comment).